# Does a UIView not require its UIViewController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Playing around in Instruments, I noticed something I don't understand. I create a couple of `UIViewController`s and add their `view`s to another `UIView`:

```
CustomVC *vc = [[CustomVC alloc] initWithCustomInitializer:someParameter];
[mainView addSubview:vc.view];
```

By logging the memory address of the CustomVC in its `init` and `dealloc`, I see that `vc` is deallocated almost immediately, though the view remains on screen and everything works fine.

Does the `UIView` not necessarily need its controller? Or is something else going on that I'm misinterpreting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIView` doesn't/shouldn't retain its parent (the `UIViewController`), so if you drop your reference to the `UIViewController` and only keep the reference to the `UIView`, nothing keeps a strong reference to it and it will be released.

The weak reference in the `UIView` to its controller will be automatically set to nil.

Whether the `UIView` needs its "lost" controller to do its work is another story though, and entirely depending on the `UIView`.

Answer (score 1):

UIView does not need ViewController by any means. What is happening is that you are probably not retaining pointer to VC. Pointer to view is retained by mainView.
Furthermore regardless wether you are using ARC or not. If you want to keep object in memory you need to have a strong(ARC) or retain property to it. Not to confuse you. It doesn't necessarily need to be your custom subclass. Lets say you are using UINavigationController. You can create a controller in app delegate for instance and push it to UINavigation controller. You dont need to keep a pointer to it as long as something does. This is very fundamental. You need to be clear on memory management I dont think I will be able to explain it here adequately. I would highly recommend you to check Stanford course on iOS development.
http://itun.es/ru/_zEGD

Comment: Neat - thanks. The view is only used briefly so I don't need it to hang around, was just curious.

Comment: I can not overstate importance of being clear on VC stuff and memory management, that course its free on itunesU, well worth watching. Its thought by paul hegarty(he worked at NeXT when they developed Objective-C)

Answer (score 0):

There should be only one UIViewController at a time. Adding a view that belongs to a viewcontroller is bad practice.

To answer your question, because of the above mentioned constraint (or design decision by Apple), the view is probably now retained by the other view controller, and released from vc.